# Can I check a website's status without actually download its content?

Tags: r, http, url, get, rate-limiting

I used the following function to get some content from an API. The problem here is, that there is a rate limit, which I usually exceed when checking URLs. Thus, I am wondering if there is another way to check URLs without opening them.

```
Updated <- function(x){http_error(GET(x))}
```

Sorry, that there is no real way to produce a good sample of

Answer (score 3):

What a nice question, this can be sometimes very useful! Maybe you can try to run `curlGetHeaders()` function. It's in base R, so you don't need to install any package. Just type:

```
curlGetHeaders("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

This should ask only for HTTP headers, not the content (just like running command-line `curl -I`) and so it can possibly bypass your rate limit (but also may not, it depends on the API provider and you need to try that first).

If you want to get the HTTP status, just run:

```
# get all HTTP headers
headers <- curlGetHeaders("https://stackoverflow.com/")

# get HTTP status code
http_status <- attributes(headers)$status
#> http_status
# [1] 200

# or full status header
headers[1]
# [1] "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
```

For more information see [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/curlGetHeaders.html) or type `?curlGetHeaders` to your R console.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I checked out the approach. However, I now only get plenty of 404 Errors. Probably this happens due to issues with the firewall, right? Or is there any other explanation?  I tried it this way:    Updated <- function(x){attributes(curlGetHeaders(x))$status}

Comment: PS: I am sorry, I didn't figure out how to format text as  code in the comments

Comment: @wwnpo01 If you get HTTP 404 status code, try to print out all the headers (`headers` in the code above). Maybe it's really the response of the web server (do you have correct url address?), otherwise you can figure out what's wrong (firewall etc) in the headers.

Comment: thank you, the url adresses are correct :) Anyways I will check out the headers :)

Comment: @wwnpo01 Try that, maybe there's no error on your side and you'll see something strange in the headers, like server error or missing redirect etc... Your piece of code seems to be OK.