# Check the status of a list of website ignoring errors in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a list of websites in a dataset I would like to know they are active or not.

I wrote a function based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432679/can-i-check-a-websites-status-without-actually-download-its-content/62437455#62437455), basically. However, `curlGetHeaders()` function stops when the URL cannot be resolved.

The code I wrote is:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Read the CSV file containing the URLs
url_list <- read.csv("./file.csv") %>%
    select(-c(4:6, 8:11, 13))

# Function to check the status code of a URL
check_status_code <- function(url) {
    headers <- curlGetHeaders(url,
                              verify = FALSE)
    http_status <- attributes(headers)$status
}

# Check the status code for each URL
status_codes <- sapply(url_list$url, check_status_code)

# Create a new CSV file with the URL and status code
data.frame(URL = url_list$url, status_code = status_codes) %>%
  write.csv("url_status_codes.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

An example of the data I have is:

```
http://www.move4ward.co.uk
[blank]
[blank]
http://physioworks.info
b2fit.co.uk
http://www.33health.co.uk
```

With blanks I got the error `URL rejected: No host part in the URL`, and with the last record I got `Could not resolve host: www.33health.co.uk`.

How can I make the script to work with all the records, even those blanks or not responding?

Comment: You could use `tryCatch` to catch errors and return a default value if curl throws an error.

Comment: use a `tryCatch()` block around code that can throw errors. Please make sure your examples are reproducible so we can copy/paste them into R for testing. Don't use functions like `read.csv` since we don't have the file on our computers. Share data using `dput()` or something similar so it can be copy/pasted for testing.

Comment: Would [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63864926/8245406) to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864739/handling-404-and-other-bad-urls-when-reading-in-r-with-read-html) help?

Comment: I used the code in the answer by @jbgruber, that works perfect with small datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `try`:

```r
check_status_code <- function(url) {
  res <- try({ # code inside try can never fail. If an error occurs, it is recorded
    headers <- curlGetHeaders(url,
                              verify = FALSE)
    attributes(headers)$status
  }, silent = TRUE)
  
  if (is(res, "try-error")) { # test if res contains an error
    return(0L)                # you can return whatever you want here. 0 seems appropriate
  } else {
    return(res)
  }
} 

url_list <- data.frame(url = c("google.com", "", "www.33health.co.uk"))

status_codes <- sapply(url_list$url, check_status_code)
status_codes
#>         google.com                    www.33health.co.uk 
#>                200                  0                  0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The reason why the function errors with blanks and broken urls is that calls to these "servers" do not produce a response with an error message, but the function itself fails. This is why you have to handle the error explicitly.